# Hide div when clicking the close button with CSS

Tags: html, css, close-button

In my application I need to have notice/warning/error boxes (DIVs) that the user can close with a button located *inside the box itself.* A problem I'm facing is that the `:has()` pseudo-class is not widely supported; otherwise I could do something like this:

```
.msgbox:has(.closeflag:checked) { display:none; }
```

(where `.msgbox` is the external div and `.closeflag` the checkbox with the close status).

Is there an alternative to do the same without using `:has()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: I don't see how it does. Basically the answers are "use `:has()`" or "use JavaScript/JQuery" or "use `:focus-within`", neither of which helps in this case.

Comment: There are no more other cases, if you can't use one of the suggested ways then you have to use Javascript. If it is a button, you shouldn't abuse a checkbox for this.

Comment: @cloned What elements other than a checkbox or a radio can store a state independently of all other elements? (and I really don't like to use a radio for this)

Comment: @cloned What is the reason you advice to not use checkboxes as css buttons ?

Comment: puerly semantic reasons. If it is a button, it should be a `<button>` You can store states easily in JS, so there is no reason to use a checkbox or radiobutton. Also I don't know how accessible these radiobutton / checkox solutions are.

Comment: @PedroGimeno what you are trying to do works with `:has`. As always, if you are not happy with the browsers support, you can use javascript for this task. It's an alternative. You can indeed change your html (answer bellow), but it does not answer the original question where the "button is located inside the box itself". That's why for me it was a duplicate ! Happy you found a workaround by your own though :)

Comment: @Brewal *"works with `:has`"* - Doesn't work for me with Firefox 102. *"you can use javascript"* - javascript could be a fallback, but my application is required to work with JS disabled. @cloned has a point about accessibility, though, so I've opened an issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1807670

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution that gets the job done:

```css
.closeflag {
  display: none;
}

.closebutton {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.closeflag:checked+.msgbox {
  display: none;
}

/* For demonstration purposes: */
.msgbox {
  border: solid 1px maroon;
}
```

```html
<input class="closeflag" id="unique-id-for-box-1" type="checkbox">
<div class="msgbox">
  <label class="closebutton" for="unique-id-for-box-1">&#10060;</label> text
</div>
```

Basically, the `<label for...>` acts as a remote control for the checkbox, which no longer needs to be inside the div (but the label itself is).